# Delphi TIdWebDav Yandex

Tags: delphi, indy, webdav

Using Delphi 2007,
Using InDy 10,
Using TIdWebDAV,
service webdav.yandex.ru,
I want to publish a file, but I get an error authorization

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
 s, r: TStringStream;
begin
  s := TStringStream.Create('<propertyupdate xmlns="DAV:">' + sLineBreak +
  '<set>'  + sLineBreak +
    '<prop>'  + sLineBreak +
      '<public_url xmlns="urn:yandex:disk:meta">true</public_url>'  + sLineBreak +
    '</prop>'  + sLineBreak +
  '</set>'  + sLineBreak +
'</propertyupdate>');

  r := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
//fill params
    IdWebDAV1.URL.Password := '*****';
    IdWebDAV1.URL.Username := '***@yandex.ru';
    IdWebDAV1.URL.Port := '80';
    IdWebDAV1.URL.URI := '/tst/readme.txt';
    IdWebDAV1.URL.Host := 'webdav.yandex.ru';
    IdWebDAV1.URL.Protocol := 'PROPFIND';

//fill OAuth ID
    IdWebDAV1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: OAuth c953e33d6ec14895aa776f55145e73b5');
    IdWebDAV1.Put('https://webdav.yandex.ru/', s, r);
//result
    Memo1.Lines.Text := r.DataString;
  finally
    s.Free;
    r.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**I get an ERROR: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.**

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `TIdWebDAV` correctly.  You should be using its `DAVPropPatch()` method instead of its `Put()` method when posting `propertyupdate` XML, and you should not be filling the `URI` property manually at all.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  q: TStringStream;
  r: TMemoryStream;
begin
  q := TStringStream.Create(
    '<propertyupdate xmlns="DAV:">' + sLineBreak +
    '<set>' + sLineBreak +
    '<prop>' + sLineBreak +
    '<public_url xmlns="urn:yandex:disk:meta">true</public_url>' + sLineBreak +
    '</prop>' + sLineBreak +
    '</set>' + sLineBreak +
    '</propertyupdate>'
  );
  try    
    r := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      IdWebDAV1.Request.Username := '***@yandex.ru';
      IdWebDAV1.Request.Password := '*****';
      IdWebDAV1.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
      IdWebDAV1.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
      IdWebDAV1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'OAuth c953e33d6ec14895aa776f55145e73b5';
      IdWebDAV1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
      IdWebDAV1.DAVPropPatch('https://webdav.yandex.ru/tst/readme.txt', q, r);
      r.Position := 0;
      Memo1.Lines.Text := ReadStringAsCharset(r, IdWebDAV1.Response.Charset);
    finally
      r.Free;
    end;
  finally
    q.Free;
  end;
end;
```